# Javascript Arrays Opposite of Includes

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

What is the correct way of removing objects that have a certain field in JavaScript?

I can include fields with the following:

```
filteredResult = filteredResult.filter(e => e.selectedFields.includes("Red"));
```

But if I wanted to remove all properties that have this field what would I do? There doesn't seem to be a "Remove" from the documentation.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Just negate it.

```
filteredResult = filteredResult.filter(e => !e.selectedFields.includes("Red"))
```

Comment: No problem, we all miss obvious things once in a while. Though on looking again I don't think the code makes much sense -- surely you want something in the filtering function to depend on the value of `e`? Maybe you meant `selectedFields.includes(e)`?

Comment: Probably `e.selectedFields.includes("Red')`

Comment: Now come to look at it, I agree, it doesn't make much sense. I think i'll need to review my filtering. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

You can negate the `includes` result or even cleaner just by using the `indexOf` property:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

const notIncludes1 = (arr, val) => !(arr.includes(0));
const notIncludes2 = (arr, val) => arr.indexOf(val) === -1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
filteredResult = filteredResult.filter((l) => (['Red', 'Blue','Yellow'].every(y => !l.selectedFields.toLowerCase().includes(y.toLowerCase()))));
```